# Using jQuery to insert tags into box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

What I’m looking to create is something like the Stack overflow tag insert. I want to be able to type the tag into the insert box and when I click the ‘Add’ button, it adds it to the box above. I also want it to push the new tag into the ‘SelectedTags’ array. If the user removes it from the box, it'll need to be removed from the array. I guess I would need to push into the array first then populate the box based on the arrays content? I’ve tried creating it in JSFiddle but can’t get it working. Can someone help using the JSFiddle example? http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/117/

I assume this is what make it look like a tag?

```
$("#tags").tagit({
  availableTags: SelectedTags
});
```

Comment: Here is a closer link: I realised about half way doing it that I was doing all your hard work. Here's one step closer. All you need to do is remove from an array now: http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/122/

Comment: This is perfect thank you! :)

Comment: No worries. I will happily point you in the right direction if you get stuck on anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sampleTags = [];

  $('#tags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
    console.log(ui.tagLabel)
      for(var i = 0; i < sampleTags.length; i++) {
        if (sampleTags[i] == ui.tagLabel) {
          sampleTags.splice(i, 1); //Here is the update
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var inp = $('#tagInput').val();
    $('#tagInput').val('');
    $('#tags').tagit('createTag', inp);
    sampleTags.push(inp);
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(sampleTags)
  });

  $("#array").click(function(e){
    console.log("MyArray",sampleTags)
  })
});
```

Try out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/131/), and when you add something to the SelectedTags array you will then have the tags as "find wile type" in the tags input.

Comment: All that needs now is to remove from array when removed from box, do you have any idea on how to do this?  http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/122/

Comment: I have updated my post and the fiddle, now the item is deleted from the array

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! I have a question, let say you add 3 words into a list e.g. "["Ryan", "Garrett", "Hello"]". In this build you have to delete them in order to delete everything from the array. So lets say I deleted Ryan from the 3 words first. It would delete Hello from the array and not Ryan. Would you know how to solve this? Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/130/

Comment: So, now everything is working correct. Check out the new code and the updated fiddle in the link above.

Comment: Thank you! Amazing help!